# Detail Text View of Cell not showing?

Tags: ios, ios4, ipad

Hi I started writing a split view app for iPad using the split-view template. In the root view controller (the table view on the left) I am trying to set the detail text label of the cells like this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
```

However when I run the app only the main text label (the label on the left of the cell). There is nothing that shows up in the detail label.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure that your cell is created as UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Answer (score 5):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text =  @"Heading";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"DetailValue";

 return cell;
```

Options :

UITableViewCellStyleValue1,     // like in Settings App )

UITableViewCellStyleValue2,     // Contacts style

UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    // DetailText in Grey.

Comment: I am using ```Value1``` and it doesn't show the ```detailTextLabel``` text.